# Displaying XML tags in labels

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

I’m trying to parse an XML file having ‘n’ number of questions using Objective C. I have to display those questions in labels at runtime in a view. That means ‘n’ labels for ‘n’ questions and ‘n’ labels for ‘n’ answers too. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to do this?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the XML format and what technologies you intend to use to parse it and to display the results.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need to use the NSXMLDocument class to parse the XML file. Take a look at the documentation either at developer.apple.com or within Xcode by selecting "Documentation" under the Help menu.

Search for NSXMLDocument. Read the reference or click the link to read Tree-Based XML Programming Guide for Cocoa.

You can also find some sample code at:
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.06/XMLParser/

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using one of the .NET languages to achieve this you might want to look into using a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) or a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) and dynamically create your labels and add them to the panel.

Comment: They are not using .NET, but Objective-C.